# What are the differences between wired and wireless mice?

Tags: mouse, first-person-shooter

I just bought CS:GO and I wanted to buy a gaming mouse to play CS:GO and some otherfps games, but I don't know if I should go with a wired or a wireless mouse.

What are the main differences between the two? Is there one that is recommended over the other for FPS gaming?

Comment: There isn't a "better" one, it's which one you prefer. 

Wireless mice have the advantage of less resistance to your movement as the cord on wired mice drags along the table and/or other objects. If you have a particularly messy desk then it may be difficult to accurately move the mouse if you are constantly putting objects on top of or near the wire. A [mouse bungee](http://cdn.overclock.net/9/99/99573b7c_Mouse_Bungee_3Kopie.jpeg) can help nullify a lot of the disadvantages of having a cord. One description of a mouse bungee starts with: "You'll feel as if you're using a wireless mouse"

Comment: A wireless mouse however has the disadvantages of needing to be charged regularly. This can be quite bad if you play for long periods of time or forget to charge it sometimes as the mouse may just stop working in the middle of a ranked CSGO game, which may be the difference between winning or losing. Also the battery can only be charged so much. You'll need to buy new batteries every now and then (they can last a few months to a few years). The other disadvantage of using a wireless mouse is that they are generally much heavier than wired mice.

Comment: Using Nicad or zinc-carbon batteries will bring the weight down, but also the runtime.

Comment: Its actually widely considered a standard in the gaming industry that wired > wireless. When timing really matters, a wireless transmission can delay your input enough to cost you the game.

Comment: Mice still isn't a gaming specific item, so this isn't something we should be helping with.

Comment: @Frank, if mice are auto-off topic, why is there a mouse tag?

Comment: We can definitely answer this from a gaming perspective. And there are mice that are built to be 'gaming specific' as the OP mentions

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a "better" one, it's which one you prefer.

Wireless mice have the advantage of less resistance to your movement as the cord on wired mice drags along the table and/or other objects. If you have a particularly messy desk then it may be difficult to accurately move the mouse if you are constantly putting objects on top of or near the wire. A mouse bungee can help nullify a lot of the disadvantages of having a cord. One description of a mouse bungee starts with:

> "You'll feel as if you're using a wireless mouse"

A wireless mouse however has the disadvantages of needing to be charged regularly. This can be quite bad if you play for long periods of time or forget to charge it sometimes as the mouse may just stop working in the middle of a ranked CSGO game, which may be the difference between winning or losing.

Also the battery can only be charged so much. You'll need to buy new batteries every now and then (they can last a few months to a few years). The other disadvantage of using a wireless mouse is that they are generally much heavier than wired mice, which is again dependent on personal taste but many people will have preferences for the weight of their mouse (most mice have interchangable weights) which is generally less than a lot of wireless mice.